# catch stored procedure exception in Talend

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, etl, talend, data-integration

I'm using tMysqlSP to call a stored procedure from Talend.
The procedure is failing but there is no error indication in Talend.
Tried with tMysqlRow as well, and no change.

Any ideas how to catch the DB error?

Job screenshot:
[image: Job screenshot]

Comment: can you please show the job screenshot here

Comment: I've added the pic

Comment: are you not getting your errors in Run tab?

Comment: No.  and when I'm calling the procedure in the mysql itself it does fail